# Metamask multiple getting all connected accounts

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, metamask

I'm trying to get all the Metamask wallets I have connected to my site, however, I can only get the default wallet, I'm trying something like this:

```
async function getWallets(){
    if(!window.ethereum){
      console.log('!!!!! Non-Ethereum browser detected.');
    }
    let w3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    await window.ethereum.enable();
    w3.eth.getAccounts((err, accounts) => {
      console.log('accounts', accounts)
    });
  }
```

When enabled is the call I connect multiple wallets to the site, however when I try to get the account I receive just the default account.

Comment: As far as i know there is no way to get all of the accounts , MetaMask just return the active one .
it depends on of your case, may be you need to hardcode it, or detect account changes as mention in the MetaMask doc : https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#accountschanged

Answer (score 2):

In the far past, multiple accounts were supported. Nowadays wallets return only the default connected account for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is a MetaMask design decision based on security reasons see [doc](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#eth-requestaccounts) although the original [EIP-1102](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1102.md#eth_requestaccounts) requires that the `eth_requestAccounts` method returns one or more accounts if approved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [wallet_getPermissions](https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/reference/rpc-api/#wallet_requestpermissions) does that:

```
ethereum
   .request({method: 'wallet_getPermissions'})
   .then(res => {
      console.log('Connected accounts:', res[0]?.caveats?.[0]?.value);
   })
   .catch(err => {
     console.log('Error getting permissions:', err);
   });
```

I'm not sure how reliable this is but it does return array of connected accounts.